# What's the name and purpose of this metallic frame at the base of a tree?

Tags: identification, trees

In the city where I live, I've seen metallic frames like this one in various places, at the base of the trees. The tree is already big, I don't think it will prevent it from growing in one direction or another.

And is there any reason for it to be inclined?

[image]

[image: second]

[image: third]

[image: inclined]
[image: straight]

Comment: I'm not sure its actually a tree guard - why would this tree be the only one in the street to have such a structure around it, doesn't make sense,they should all have them if that's all it is.  It's possible that, because this tree was inclined, they put it there for it to 'lean' on,  but does it have another purpose,this frame? Its not unlike the sort of thing one would padlock a bicycle to , but difficult to say if its tall enough for that. And its the first tree guard I've seen that's so basic, utilitarian and rather ugly - I suspect it has another purpose of some sort.

Comment: Meanwhile I've found another one. It's also inclined. The legs are longer on the side the tree is inclined. The size of the legs is comparable with a car wheel - some 40 cm (16 inches).

Comment: So they've only put them round trees that are leaning or inclined - its gotta be some sort of attempt to reduce the inclination of the tree... I'd be intrigued enough to contact whoever's in charge of street furniture and planting to find out exactly what they're for and how they work round trees which are leaning.  They're not tree guards as such, for a start, they're too open, wouldn't prevent animals,kids or people from scratching or damaging the bark at the base....

Comment: I'll try to find more, and when I see some workers on the street I'll ask.

Comment: I doubt so large trees can 'lean on' this comparably small metal objects. For example, can you lean on something that is 50 times smaller than you?? :-)

Comment: I'll be interested to know what you find out, Fructibus

Comment: Today I've found three more. I've uploaded the photos. These guards are not inclined. The last tree is also not inclined. They are all on the sidewalk and close to the curb. Their height is equal with a car wheel. Therefore they must be "anti-car tree guards". Meanwhile I've found a NY photo with two anti-car guards - https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/57/Bedford_St_sidewalk_jeh.JPG/800px-Bedford_St_sidewalk_jeh.JPG

Comment: From ten or fifteen trees, only one has it - but I maybe they are placed at the  intersections or near pedestrian crossings. I will check. I will also keep in mind to ask the urbanization workers when I'll find them. I wonder if these low-height tree guards have a distinct name.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The most common names for such structures are 'metal tree guard' and 'metal tree trunk guard'.

The purpose is to protect the tree from mechanical impact of other heavy moving objects, such as cars, buses, people (especially overweight), and keeping such objects away from the tree.

Some metal tree guards have an aesthetic/decorative purpose too. An example:

[image: Black decorative tree trunk guard]